# Teleport API: Access JSON Object properties

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am learning some things about API calls in Javascript. For this, I make a call to the teleport api.

From there I get an Json object back. Now I would like to access the link which you can see in the "json object" below.

```
_embedded
    city:search-results     [25]
    0
    _links
    city:item
    href:   https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/geonameid:2661552/
```

I have a problem with the "city:search-results" key, because I cant use a the ":" in the dotted notation.

so, how can I get the href value?

I hope its understandable, im sorry for the bad explanation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried? If you receive the JSON data, you should be able to access properties of the data as if it were a JavaScript object using [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics#dot_notation) or [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics#bracket_notation). See [Object literal notation vs JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#object_literal_notation_vs_json)

Comment: @phentnil I tried it with "_embedded.city:search-results[0]" to get the first entry but the ":" makes it wrong.

Comment: @phentnil I managed to do it with the bracket notation, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see how the JSON is returned. For [this example](https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/), use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics#bracket_notation) for `city:search-results` as

```js
_embedded["city:search-results"][0]
```

And for accessing the `href` property:

```js
_embedded["city:search-results"][0]["_links"]["city:item"]["href"]
```

Example code (with 2 `city:search-results` objects):

```js
var _embedded = {
  "city:search-results": [{
      "_links": {
        "city:item": {
          "href": "https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/geonameid:1796236/"
        }
      },
      "matching_alternate_names": [],
      "matching_full_name": "Shanghai, Shanghai, China"
    },
    {
      "_links": {
        "city:item": {
          "href": "https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/geonameid:745044/"
        }
      },
      "matching_alternate_names": [],
      "matching_full_name": "Istanbul, Istanbul, Turkey"
    }
  ]
};
console.log(_embedded["city:search-results"][0]["_links"]["city:item"]["href"]);
```